# How to Optimize below query for specified code

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT a.id, a.stock_num, a.stock_rfrnc_num,
       a.date, a.center, a.owner,
       a.owner_id, a.product_typ, a.transaction_dt,
       a.location, a.status
  FROM a
 WHERE a.status = 'Ready'
   AND a.owner_id != 'stockholder' 
    AND a.owner_id='stockseller'
      AND (a.product_typ = '03' OR a.product_typ = '04');
```

product type is from 1 to 5 ,
owner_id has six types,
status has 5 types,
can this be optimized further ?

Comment: `EXPLAIN PLAN` please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in operator instead of or.

```
AND a.product_typ in ('03','04');
```

Below line is not neccesary.

```
 AND a.owner_id != 'stockholder'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.stock_num, a.stock_rfrnc_num,
       a.date, a.center, a.owner,
       a.owner_id, a.product_typ, a.transaction_dt,
       a.location, a.status
  FROM a
 WHERE a.status = 'Ready'
    AND a.owner_id='stockseller'
      AND a.product_typ in ('03','04');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite `B-Tree index` with `leading column` as `status`.

`create index index_name on table_name(status, owner_id, product_typ)`

Note the leading column in the index. You could create a `unique` index if you are sure of the uniqueness of the data. The above would create a `NORMAL` index which is by defualt `NON-UNIQUE`.

Your predicate seems unnecessarily complicated. The following makes no sense -

```
 AND a.owner_id != 'stockholder' 
    AND a.owner_id='stockseller'
```

Remove the not equal filter from the predicate, as the rows will be filtered by `AND a.owner_id != 'stockholder'`.

And check the `explain plan` of the query if the indexes are being used or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the index Lalit Kumar suggested you probably best of using a `UNION ALL` instead of the `OR` in your where clause. If this is the only query used on this table you might want to make that index the clustered index. Otherwise you might consider to include all the required columns in the index.

```
SELECT a.id, a.stock_num, a.stock_rfrnc_num,
       a.date, a.center, a.owner,
       a.owner_id, a.product_typ, a.transaction_dt,
       a.location, a.status
  FROM a
 WHERE a.status = 'Ready'
    AND a.owner_id = 'stockseller'
    AND a.product_typ = '03'

UNION ALL

SELECT a.id, a.stock_num, a.stock_rfrnc_num,
       a.date, a.center, a.owner,
       a.owner_id, a.product_typ, a.transaction_dt,
       a.location, a.status
  FROM a
 WHERE a.status = 'Ready'
    AND a.owner_id = 'stockseller'
    AND a.product_typ = '04';
```